# How do I unregister a Handler in net/http?

Tags: http, go

I am writing a web server wherein I need to register handlers at runtime. E.g. "/create" would create a new handler for all URLs like "/123/*" and so on. I need a corresponding "/destroy/123" which would unregister the handler for "/123/*".

Here's the code for handling "/create"

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

type MyHandler struct {
    id int
}
func (hf *MyHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintln(w, r.URL.Path)
}

// Creates MyHandler instances and registers them as handlers at runtime
type HandlerFactory struct {
    handler_id int
}
func (hf *HandlerFactory) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    hf.handler_id++
    handler := MyHandler{hf.handler_id}
    handle := fmt.Sprintf("/%d/", hf.handler_id)
    http.Handle(handle, &handler)
}

func main() {
    factory := HandlerFactory{0}
    http.Handle("/create", &factory)
    http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8080", nil)
}
```

I tried implementing my own multiplexer by embedding `http.ServeMux` but it holds its pattern-to-Handler mapping in a private variable (`ServeMux.m`)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What I would do is create a custom `ServerMux`. Copy the code from `GOROOT/src/pkg/net/http/server.go`. It starts on line 837 and ends at 939.

The custom ServerMux would need a method for deregistration. This should be easy to implement. Just grab the lock and `del()` the map entry. For example (all code untested):

```
// TODO: check if registered and return error if not.
// TODO: possibly remove the automatic permanent link between /dir and /dir/.
func (mux *MyMux) Deregister(pattern string) error {
    mux.mu.Lock()
    defer mux.mu.Unlock()
    del(mux.m, pattern)
    return nil
}
```

In order to use this new mux, you would do something like this:

```
mux := newMux()
mux.Handle("/create", &factory)

srv := &http.Server {
    Addr: localhost:8080
    Handler: mux,
}
srv.ListenAndServe()
```

Modifying mux by calling `deregister()` from another goroutine is completely safe and will modify the way `ListenAndServe()` routes messages.

Answer (score 9):

It appears you've already accepted an answer, but I wanted to propose an alternate solution.

I question the need for adding a custom muxer. In this example I'm using the gorilla muxer, however that's only because I'm familiar with its pattern matching. In theory you could match the pattern from the incoming URL without the need for replacing the default muxer.

My code maintains the handler functions in a map (string: the handler name => function literal)... This is suitable for using the default muxers HandleFunc method.

Sample input/output:

GET /register/123

GET /123
`hello from123.`

GET /destroy/123

GET /123
`[nothing]`

```
package main

import (
    "code.google.com/p/gorilla/mux"
    "flag"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

// Wraps server muxer, dynamic map of handlers, and listen port.
type Server struct {
    Dispatcher *mux.Router
    Urls       map[string]func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)
    Port       string
}

// May the signal never stop.
func main() {
    //Initialize Server
    server := &Server{Port: "3000", Dispatcher: mux.NewRouter(), Urls: make(map[string]func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request))}

    var port = flag.String("port", "3000", "Default: 3000; Set the port for the web-server to accept incoming requests")
    flag.Parse()

    server.Port = *port
    log.Printf("Starting server on port: %s \n", server.Port)

    server.InitDispatch()
    log.Printf("Initializing request routes...\n")

    server.Start() //Launch server; blocks goroutine.
}

func (s *Server) Start() {

    http.ListenAndServe(":"+s.Port, s.Dispatcher)
}

// Initialize Dispatcher's routes.
func (s *Server) InitDispatch() {
    d := s.Dispatcher

    // Add handler to server's map.
    d.HandleFunc("/register/{name}", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        //somewhere somehow you create the handler to be used; i'll just make an echohandler
        vars := mux.Vars(r)
        name := vars["name"]

        s.AddFunction(w, r, name)
    }).Methods("GET")

    d.HandleFunc("/destroy/{name}", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        vars := mux.Vars(r)
        name := vars["name"]
        s.Destroy(name)
    }).Methods("GET")

    d.HandleFunc("/{name}", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        //Lookup handler in map and call it, proxying this writer and request
        vars := mux.Vars(r)
        name := vars["name"]

        s.ProxyCall(w, r, name)
    }).Methods("GET")
}

func (s *Server) Destroy(fName string) {
    s.Urls[fName] = nil //remove handler
}

func (s *Server) ProxyCall(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, fName string) {
    if s.Urls[fName] != nil {
        s.Urls[fName](w, r) //proxy the call
    }
}

func (s *Server) AddFunction(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, fName string) {
    f := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte("hello from" + fName))
    }

    s.Urls[fName] = f // Add the handler to our map
}
```

Comment: Your solution is pretty good. This is probably what I would have done if basic URL structure interpretation was part of the standard library.

My requirement is currently not complex enough to bring in a new package, but I suspect it won't take too many iterations for it to be so and I might go for Gorilla at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the unregistering can be "done" by registering a handler returning nothing (not writing anything to the ResponseWriter) or generating a 'not found' kind of response. Depends on your requirements and/or purpose/effect of the unregistering of a previously registered handler.

Comment: The concern is that the handler registry will keep growing over time and cause a slowdown in request turnaround due to increasingly expensive handler lookups.