# why does http.ServeMux have no Remove method?

Tags: go

Why does `http.ServeMux` not have a `Remove` method like so:

```
// Remove url from m, Regularization is not considered
func (mux *ServeMux) Remove(url string) {
    mux.mu.Lock()
    defer mux.mu.Unlock()
    delete(mux.m, url)
}
```

Comment: Does [How do I unregister a Handler in net/http?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738029/how-do-i-unregister-a-handler-in-net-http) answer your question?

Comment: There is no actual reason. The authors just decided that ServeMux as is is fine. (And why would anybody decide to stop handling a certain route?)

Answer (score 3):

There is more to `ServeMux` than just the routing `map`.

From the [source](https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go?s=69181:69383#L2212) there's a length-ordered slice of all routes `es` - which determines route-precedent:

```
type ServeMux struct {
    mu    sync.RWMutex
    m     map[string]muxEntry
    es    []muxEntry // slice of entries sorted from longest to shortest.
    hosts bool       // whether any patterns contain hostnames
}
```

if one were to fork their own `ServeMux` then `es` would need to be updated upon route removal.

---

It it hard to envision a practical need to dynamically remove a route. Even it was implemented, `ServeMux` would still "handle" the removed route - returning a `404` (Not Found) status error.

If one wanted to *disable* a route, putting this dynamic logic within the handler itself, returning a `404` - or `401` (Unauthorized) or `403` (Forbidden) - directly seems easier and more natural.